# How to create a table with manual data on the fly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c, oracle21c

Let's say I want to define some tabular data on the fly to use in a query, without creating a physical table:

```
+------------+------------+
|COLUMN_VALUE|COLUMN_VALUE|
+------------+------------+
|1           |a           |
|2           |b           |
|5           |e           |
|4           |d           |
|3           |c           |
+------------+------------+
```

(note the ordering)

How can I do this as succinctly and simply as possible?

What I could come up with (not so pretty):

```
with
    x as (
        select
            column_value
        from
            table (sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 5, 4, 3))),

    y as (
        select
            column_value
        from
            table (sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'c')))
select
    x.column_value,
    y.column_value
from
    x
inner join y on x.rownum = y.rownum;
```

However this does not work, as it errors out with `ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`. Apparently the `rownum` pseudocolumn is not supported when using the built-in `table()` function.

Using `row_number() over (order by column_value asc)` in the CTE's seems to wor, but forces ordering of the column values. This is undesirable as the values should appear in the order in which they are defined in the table function.

Comment: What's wrong with `select 1,'a' from dual union all ..` ?

Comment: The rownum pseudocolumn is indeed supported when using the built-in table() operator. What's not supported is a reference to `x.rownum` for any subquery `x`. `x.columnname` can only refer to explicitly named columns of `x`. `rownum` would require an alias or double quotes because it is a keyword.

Comment: @Serg the fact that it is not succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a community suggestion on the Oracle Database Ideas forum to [add an `ordinality` pseudocolumn to scalar collections](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4491649/pseudocolumn-for-ordinality-of-table-collection-expression), but I'd say it's unlikely to be implemented in our lifetimes. There is also a suggestion for syntax to allow sets to be declared on the fly using a `values` clause similar to [Postgres Values lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html), though I can't find it right now.

Currently your options are:

1. Use multiple `select from dual` queries with `union all` to define all required rows explicitly.
2. Define custom object and collection types in order to use `table()` and object declarative syntax.

I agree neither is ideal.

Example of the `select from dual` approach:

```
with test_data (id, somevalue) as
     (
       select 1, 'a' from dual union all
       select 2, 'b' from dual union all
       select 5, 'e' from dual union all
       select 4, 'd' from dual union all
       select 3, 'c' from dual
     )
select id, somevalue
from   test_data
```

Regarding generated row numbering, you can use

```
row_number() over(order by null)
```

Technically this is not guaranteed to preserve the order, but it seems to do so in practice as of Oracle 21c.

```
select column_value
     , row_number() over (order by null) as rn
from   table (sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'c'));

COLUMN_VALUE         RN
------------ ----------
a                     1
b                     2
e                     3
d                     4
c                     5
```

Regarding your ORA-01747 error for `x.rownum`, this is not because of any restriction around the `table()` operator. There are two issues with a construction like this (simplified version of your query):

```
with demo as
     ( select dummy from dual )
select x.rownum from demo x
```

1. CTE `demo` doesn't have a column named 'rownum'. It only has one column (`dummy`) so that's the only x.column you can refer to.
2. Even if you add `rownum` to the query, you can't refer to it as a column like `x.rownum` because it's a keyword. The solution would be to alias it within the CTE as something like 'seq' or 'rn' which is then OK to refer to:

```
with demo as
     ( select dummy, rownum as rn from dual )
select x.rn from demo x
```

Comment: I didn't know you could order by null, useful to know! Your answer is informative, but it misses the point slightly as it doesn't show how one can create multiple columns/tuples of data. My solution (see below) uses an inner join on the row number for this purpose. If you can include this (or another way for doing this) I'll mark your post as the solution.

Comment: That was the bit about multiple "select from dual" queries with "union all" or defining custom objects. Joining multiple scalar collections on their row number will work but I think it gets complicated too quickly to be a generic solution.

Comment: Added example of the `select from dual` approach.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to alias the rownum column (also tidied up the query):

```
select
    x.column_value,
    y.column_value
from
    (select column_value, rownum as rn from table (sys.odcinumberlist(1, 2, 5, 4, 3))) x
        inner join
        (select column_value, rownum as rn from table (sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'c'))) y on x.rn = y.rn;
```